# Text over footer image

Tags: html, css, image, text

I want to have a copyright text over my footer image, so i made a paragraph with the id "copyright". This is in my css file:

```
.footer {
background: url(../images/footer_extend.png) repeat-x center;
overflow: hidden;
 }
.footer img {
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
    max-width:970px;
    height: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#copyright{
position:absolute;
color:#000;
bottom:1px;
left:46%;
}
```

So the text should be centered, white and at the very bottom of the page. But for me, the text is in the middle of the page (not at the bottom). Why and how can I fix that?

Oh, this is my html file:

```
<div class="footer">
    <img src="images/footer.png" width="970" height="130" alt="" />
    <p id="copyright">© 2013</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: If you add `position:relative;` to your footer class, it should solve the issue.

Comment: If you want the text on top of the image you probably will want to keep it absolutely positioned. Where is your footer image showing up?? At the bottom of the page or the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `div#copyright` to be absolutely positioned relative to `div.footer`, `div.footer` needs to be relatively positioned.

By default, divs are [positioned statically](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning#Static_positioning), so you'll need to explicitly specify relative position:

```
.footer {
    position:relative;
    background: url(../images/footer_extend.png) repeat-x center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Working example below:

```css
.footer {
  position: relative;
  background: url(../images/footer_extend.png) repeat-x center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 970px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#copyright {
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 46%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <img src="images/footer.png" width="970" height="130" alt="" />
  <p id="copyright">© 2013</p>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cDc2e/)

Comment: That worked, but now hte background is not "connecting" to the end of the page, there is some space

Comment: How tall is the background image? Is it at least 130px height (like the footer)?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that issue. If possible, please clarify what you are seeing. http://jsfiddle.net/cDc2e/1/

Comment: I don't know why but is seems like the background image is being pushed upwards maybe 5 px. even "bottom:0px;" and margin 0 did not fix htat

Comment: Are you saying the footer is pushed up from the bottom of the browser window? If that's the case, we'll need to see more of your code than just the footer.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to add `position: relative` to .footer

Comment: but now the background is not "connecting" to the end of the page, there is some space on the bottom

Comment: Do you have this running somewhere? Or a fiddle?